# What is the difference between {} and {0} as struct initialisers?

Tags: c, struct, initialization

Is there any difference between this:

```
struct something s = {};
```

And this?

```
struct something s = {0};
```

From all I know, both initialise every member to zero.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`struct something s = {};` isn't valid C <strike>(unless they added it in C11)</strike>, but is valid C++. GCC seems to allow it in C programs as an extension (though I don't see it mentioned in the docs on http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html, but I might just be missing it).

In C++ it will result in 'value-initialization', which basically means that the default constructor is called for each member (zero-initialization for non-class members).

Comment: FYI, this hasn't been added to C11, `{0}` still is the catch-all initializer for C and `{}` is a syntax error.

Comment: @JensGustedt Unfortunately, GCC has started to disagree in recent years and emits nuisance diagnostics for `{0}`, when the `0` matches some inner aggregate, which you have to shut up by using `{{0}}` or similar.

Comment: @Kaz, yes, it is really annoying. For gcc "missing braces" is one of the warnings that I switch off systematically, just for that reason.

Comment: `-Wno-missing-braces -Wno-missing-field-initializers` are standard options in my gcc build scripts.